# A problem with a non-abelian group i cannot understand

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have this problem, $p$ and $q$ prime numbers, $G$ is a non-abelian group and $|G|=pq$.
I have to prove that $Z(G)=\{e\}$.
So, I know from theory that, for example if $Z(G)=p$ then $G\setminus Z(G)=q$, and $q$ is prime so $G\setminus Z(G)$ is cyclic and it is abelian.
My question is- If $Z(G)=p$ and $G\setminus Z(G)=q$ then $|Z(G)\cup(G\setminus Z(G))|=|G|=p+q$.
But the problem says there are $pq$ elements in $G$, and $pq$ does not equal $p+q$. I think I'm missing something but I really cannot figure it out. Please, can you help me?

Comment: Why would you take union of $Z(G)$ and $G/Z(G)$? It does not make sense; one is set of elements of $G$ while the other is a set of cosets.
Another thing, mind that "\" denotes the setminus operator while "/" denotes a quotient structure.

Comment: You are confusing the [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement) $B\color{red}\setminus A=\{x\in B\mid x\notin A\}$ and the [quotient group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) $G\color{red}/H=\{gH\mid g\in G\}$.

Comment: Please use LaTeX and a more concrete title.

Comment: If $|Z(G)|=p$, then $|G\setminus Z(G)|=$ $pq-p=$ $p(q-1)$.